# $_GET[] doesn't work in included file?

Tags: php, scope, superglobals

I have a webpage which holds the number of the page to display:

```
mydomain.net/index.php?page=42
```

This works alright. Now I want to display the page only when a particular cookie is set, and I moved most of the body to an include file, so that index.php only has

```
<?php 
    if ($cookie_ok):
        include("http://mydomain.net/index_d6skrif9.php"); 
    else:
        include("http://mydomain.net/noaccess.inc"); 
    endif 
?>
```

and now the `$_GET["page"]` in the include file, which is supposed to retrieve the page number returns nothing.

I read that `$_GET[]` is a superglobal and that superglobals' scopes are across include files. So what's wrong here, and how can I use the page number in the include file?

Comment: You're not including another PHP file. You are retrieving the HTML output over your webserver. And this *basically remote* PHP process won't see the local superglobals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include them locally, not over-the-web:

```
if ($cookie_ok) 
    include("index_d6skrif9.php"); 
else
    include("noaccess.inc"); 
endif
```

By using URLs, you're making a web-request and the server executes the PHP in the file and returns the contents (making it have its own set of super-globals).

Answer (score 3):

`$_GET` works in included **files**, it does not work in included HTTP resources.

The PHP in `index_d6skrif9.php` will be executed by `mydomain.net` before it gets to the PHP program with the `include` statement in it.

Use a local file path, not an HTTP URL.

```
include("index_d6skrif9.php");
```

Alternatively, pass the value to the server you are pulling the include from:

```
include("http://mydomain.net/index_d6skrif9.php?page=" + urlencode($_GET['page']));
```

Note that the latter approach has far more opportunity for things to go wrong and is much less efficient than a local file included, so it isn't recommended if you can help it.